# How to read data.parquet.gz file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, parquet

How to read file *data.parquet.gz* and convert it into a pandas dataframe?

Below code is giving error:

> Could not open Parquet input source '': Parquet magic bytes
> not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a
> parquet file.

```
df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet.gz')
```

Answer (score 1):

You file is an gzip archive, you can to read is like so:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('data.parquet.gz', 'rb') as f:
  df = pd.read_parquet(f)
```